# Is it possible for first party cookies set by a.com to somehow know that the user also visited b.com (i.e. able to read the url)?

Tags: encryption, web-application, web-browser, cookies

Is it possible for some malicious website (a.com) to set a first party cookie in my desktop browser when I visit a.com and use it to read other URLs I'm browsing? Any hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it: **no**. Just setting a cookie does not allow `a.com` to find out about you visiting `b.com`. In fact, `a.com` cannot (under regular circumstances) access cookies from any domain outside their own scope and vice versa. This is enforced by the **[same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)**. Exceptions may be defined by the website creating the cookie by utilizing [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

However, if `a.com` somehow manages to embed, say an advertisement or something else in `b.com`, the situation changes. As you visit `b.com`, your browser contacts `a.com/ad_on_b.php` (or any other source on `a.com`) in order to load the content of said advertisement and usually includes the previously set cookie as it matches the domain. In this case, `a.com` receives a request containing your cookie and can easily tell, that this request was caused by somebody visiting `b.com` (as they know which file they include on `b.com`).

Furthermore, due to the cookie included in the request, they know, that this particular request came from **you** yielding the conclusion, that **you** visited **b.com**.

In general, such techniques are used to track users across multiple websites. **Many** advertisement companies and other data gathering organizations use them to collect as much data as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you think a browser extension on the other hand could capture such details, like having access to URL history of the browser?

Comment: Browser Extensions are an entirely different subject. AdBlockers for example HAVE to read and manipulate the entire page's content. Others may read your browser history, yes. Installing a malicious browser extension is dangerous for a variety of reasons.